# Something is wrong with unix script

Tags: bash, unix

Following is my script, every time I run this it goes into else part. when I run the TEST2EVAL command it gives me `1`

```
#!/bin/sh
TEST2EVAL='ps auxf | grep some.jar | grep -v grep | wc -l'
if [ "$TEST2EVAL" = 1 ]
then
java -jar /path/to/jar &
else
echo "Running"
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In in order save the output of a command in a variable, you have to enclose the command in backticks (`` ` ``), not single quotes (`'`).  Thus, change the second line of your script to:

```
TEST2EVAL=`ps auxf | grep some.jar | grep -v grep | wc -l`
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are trying to find out if any processes are running with `some.jar` on their command lines you probably want:

```
if pgrep -f some.jar; then
    echo running;
else
    echo not running;
fi
```

Comment: yes, trying to find a process, and if its not running, would like to start it! its working now!

Comment: @sssV It should probably be pointed out that this isn't testing for a `java` process using that jar. Anything touching that jar (or any other file with the same name) will trip that "already running" detection.

Comment: yeah, will use unique name and will be using this script for cronjob

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong quotes for command substitution: not single quotes:

```
TEST2EVAL='ps auxf | grep some.jar | grep -v grep | wc -l'
```

but backquotes:

```
TEST2EVAL=`ps auxf | grep some.jar | grep -v grep | wc -l`
```

Better yet, use `TEST2EVAL=$(ps auxf | grep some.jar | grep -v grep | wc -l)` instead. It's much clearer, supported by all POSIX-compatible shells, and can be nested more easily when necessary.